# Booting Into Black Screen

Tags: boot

For whatever reason my machine is booting into a black screen. When I press the power button it will display the purple background with the Ubuntu logo and turn off.

I tried booting with a live CD but the top 'Reinstall Ubuntu' option is greyed out. Why is that?

Pressing ESC brings up the GNU GRUB screen:

- Ubuntu.
- Advanced Options.
- Mem Test.
- Mem Test.

When I go into advanced options and try 'Run in graphical safemode' I can't see the cursor to select anything. I can hover over stuff (with no cursor) but can't click on them. Enter, Tab, arrows to nothing.

Comment: Try opening the virtual console with  Ctrl + Alt + F2 , login there, and run `sudo service lightdm restart` .

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You could try boot from live cd, and then enter this in the terminal:

```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yaunnu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it might work fine this way.